# Conditional Rendering of sources in REACT-ADMIN?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-admin, conditional-rendering

how can I check if a source exists??? QUESTION ABOUT CONDITIONAL RENDERING OF SOURCES IN REACT-ADMIN

Check out my frontend:

Sometimes, the source "dateStart" is stored as:

```
 {
report_request: {
  dateStart: 'whatever1'
dateEnd: 'watever2'
}
}
```

and OTHER TIMES, they are stored as:

```
 {
report_request: 
{dates: {
 dateStart: 'whatever1'
dateEnd: 'watever2'}
}
}
```

So I want to tell react-admin like hey.. If you can't get the startDate via source="report_request.dateStart", then try source="report_request.dates.dateStart"

How can I do this in react-admin???

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom field that renders either field depending on the value:

```
import { useRecordContext, DateField } from 'react-admin';

const ReportRequestDateField = () => {
   const record = useRecordContext();
   if (!record) return null;
   return record.report_request.dateStart
       ? <DateField source="report_request.dateStart" />
       : <DateField source="report_request.dates.dateStart" />;
};

ReportRequestDateField.defaultProps = { label: 'Start Date' };
```

Mode info at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#conditional-formatting

Comment: I tried your code, and I added a label to DateField, however when I put  inside the 
<List>
  <DataGrid>
    <ReportRequestDateField />
  <Datagrid>
</List>

The label ISN'T working. The column doesn't have a header. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that you must add this line: `ReportRequestDateField.defaultProps = { label: 'Start Date' };`. See the [Writing your own Field tutorial](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component) for more details. I've updated my reply accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
report_request.dateStart || report_request.dates.dateStart
```